# What is the difference between distinct and unique in Power query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

In sql distinct (on column - `select count(column) from table`) means rows excluding null, duplicates and non-duplicates increment the counter by 1.

Where as distinct (on * - `select count(*) from table`) means rows including null, and increment logic is same as above.

In Power bi, distinct seems to be same as sql's distinct on `count(*)` logic. And unique means count of values that do not repeat. Is that correct?

Do both consider nulls and blanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique are the number of values which appear **only once.**

Distinct are the number of individual values excluding any duplicates.

e.g.

```
a
b
b
c
c
```

One unique (a) and three distinct (a, b, c)

**UPDATE**

Below shows how nulls and blanks are treated.

[image]

5 distinct and 3 unique (nulls and blanks are reported as Empty or Empty String as below)

[image]

Comment: What about null and blanks?

Comment: So both unique and distinct in Power BI consider null and blanks?

Comment: I'll update the answer with clarification.